# How to fix media queries in css?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, media-queries

I need to create desktop and mobile versions of the site. I decided to use media queries in CSS. But when I coded them, I found out that they aren't working and I don't know how to fix them. To fix this issue I went to Youtube where found this example, but I implemented that I found that the media query doesn't work. Then I went to stack and found a similar problem. In that case, it was fixed by adding a meta tag in the head. I did that, but it didn't help me. It wasn't work in chrome and Mozilla.

```css
body{
    color:red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600){
    body{
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>The car dealer site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Title</h1><br>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the units for your max-width property. Change the line

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600){
```

to

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
```

And try it again